# How to load and use ttf font from jar

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d, truetype

Trying to write a class:

```
private void gameLevel(Graphics g) {
  try {
     InputStream fnt_stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/iomanoid.ttf");
     Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fnt_stream);
     Font Iomanoid = new Font("Iomanoid", Font.BOLD, 40);

     String msg = "Level";
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     g.setFont(Iomanoid);
     g.drawString(msg, 111,111);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

The message appears, but not with the font specified.

Comment: On a side note, you forgot to `close()` the input stream. Use `try-finally` or `try-with-resources`. Oh, and `fnt_stream` doesn't conform to proper Java style (only MULTI_WORD_CONSTANTS are allowed to contain underscores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside other comments

replace

```
Font Iomanoid = new Font("Iomanoid", Font.BOLD, 40);
```

by

```
Font iomanoid = myFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40f);
```

this font needs afterwards to be registered (as mentioned by mushfek0001)

For more information about fonts have a look at the Oracle tutorial about [Physical and Logical Fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register the newly created font in `GraphicsEnvironment`. Like this

```
try {
     GraphicsEnvironment ge =  GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
     ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("path/to/your/font/sampleFont.ttf"));
} catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
     //Handle exception
}
```

Take a look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html#bundling-physical-fonts-with-your-application).